# How can I install Jekyll on Ubuntu 10.04 Server?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, jekyll

The definitive guide to installing Jekyll seems to be https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll where it says:

```
gem install jekyll
```

I am getting an

```
ERROR:  could not find gem jekyll locally or in a repository
```

regardless of whether I run that command as superuser or not.
`gem env` Returns the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.2.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.github.com/", "http://gems.rubyforge.org/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.github.com/
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

I have also tried specifying github as the source with no luck. What else should I be trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very outdated version of RubyGems.

First, update the sources:

```
$ gem sources --clear-all
$ gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
$ gem sources --add http://gems.github.com
```

Then try to install it.

You should also login as a superuser and update the RubyGems version. 
The current release is 1.3.7.

Comment: Github has stopped building gems, http://gems.github.com/, they refer to rubygems.org now..! :)