# unable to install jekyll on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, jekyll

I am following [this guide](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/install) to install jekyll on OSX 10.7.3 and came up with the problem

`ERROR:  could not find gem jekyll locally or in a repository`

I have tried:

1. `sudo gem update --system` (and get `Nothing to update`)
2. this post: [How can I install Jekyll on Ubuntu 10.04 Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450053/how-can-i-install-jekyll-on-ubuntu-10-04-server) , and it's no use.

I am not familiar with ruby and gem but I think this is needed:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/enzo/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org", "http://gems.github.com"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
     - http://gems.github.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything specifically about Jekyll, but there might very well be issues when running it with the system Ruby (that is, the one that comes with Mac OS).

Before wasting too much time bothering with the system Ruby (which could arguably be better left untouched), try to get either [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) working. They allow you to install as many different versions of Ruby as you want without messing with the system Ruby, with each installation having its own gems.

Since you're not familiar with Ruby, I'll add that using rbenv or rvm is how most Ruby kids get their job done. Yes, it is an additional step that gets in the way, but it really does facilitate a smoother experience.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend removing gems.github.com from your gem sources unless you really need it. GitHub ceased building gems from git repositories back in 2010. If you cannot remove it, then I recommend installing jekyll with the following command:

```
gem install --source http://rubygems.org jekyll
```

My rubygems environment for reference, as I'm on OS X 10.7.5.

```
    RubyGems Environment:
    - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
    - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
    - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
    - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
    - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - universal-darwin-11
    - GEM PATHS:
        - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
        - /Users/matt/.gem/ruby/1.8
        - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
    - GEM CONFIGURATION:
        - :update_sources => true
        - :verbose => true
        - :benchmark => false
        - :backtrace => false
        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
    - REMOTE SOURCES:
        - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Jekyll directly into a new clean install of OSX Mavericks, and then wrote a quick post so I'd remember how to do it after I next reinstall my system. I've had plenty of feedback that others have had success following my guide, and no reports of anyone having any issues:

http://internet-inspired.com/wrote/install-jekyll-in-osx-mavericks/